# We need PHP for redirects but host is not supported; can Ruby handle PHP URLs?

Tags: php, ruby, redirect

We have recently had to move our charity website to a new (shared) host (www.networksolutions.com/web-hosting/hosting-package-comparison.jsp).

The website specs are: WINDOWS OPERATING SYSTEM, MS SQL 2005, ASP.NET FRAMEWORK 2.0.

We had created URL redirects from our old site which was written in PHP to our new site in ASP which were working fine. Unfortunately the new hosting company does not have PHP as part of the Windows Hosting Package so now none of the redirects work. The Windows hosting does have Ruby on Rails.

Is there any way we can use Ruby to deal with the old PHP URLs so they are redirected to the new pages? Or could there be another way of doing it?

An example of the redirects we had were from:

```
pfaf.org/leaflets/edible_uses.php TO www.pfaf.org/user/edibleuses.aspx
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: do you have a `.htaccess` equivalent?

Comment: Ruby on the Rails? I wasn't aware that the outlook was so bad!

Comment: Why on Earth would you move to a new hosting provider that doesn't support the language your existing website is written in? Did you just play Google-roulette and pick the first option that came up?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a static list of URLs to redirect then no programming language should be needed. You can do redirects in your web server configuration. Both Apache HTTP server and IIS support this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Using_.htaccess_for_redirection

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score -2):

You can't do this. You need a service provider that supports PHP.  PHP pages are processed by the server before they are sent out to the browser.  In order to properly send the PHP pages to the browser, you need a hosting provider that supports PHP.

Comment: Thanks. It's a big job to move the whole site. I was hoping there was another alternative

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes.  If you are going to downvote an answer then you ought to leave a comment to explain why.